# Time conversion

Tags: java, time

How to convert from duration (in minutes) to hour and minutes?

For example: `hour = 8` and `minute = 25`. Now person enter `duration (in minutes) 60` for example. Now how to show `time 9:25` because duration was `60 minutes`?

Comment: How many minutes are in an hour?  Answer this, and you will have a starting point.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: [An Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocalTime provided in `java.time`.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(8, 25).plusMinutes(60);
System.out.println(time);
```

Comment: ??? Why so much manipulation? The Question simply asks to add sixty minutes. `LocalTime.of( 8 , 25 ).plusMinutes( 60 )`

Comment: Good correction. But please do not answer Questions that are obvious duplicates.

Comment: @BasilBourque I will not answer duplicates.This has been a miss.

Answer (score 0):

all date/time values in Java are internally in milliseconds.  So multiply by the right factor to get milliseconds (60000 for minutes, 3600000 for hours).  this can be added or subtracted from a date.

```
function addMinutes(startDate, minutes) {
    var millis = startDate.getTime();
    return new Date(millis + minutes*60000);
}

function addHours(startDate, hours) {
    var millis = startDate.getTime();
    return new Date(millis + hours*3600000);
}
```